# how to change checked radio button color in bootstrap

Tags: css, sass

I want to fill the radio button with orange color after checked. By default color is blue

```
                <h5>Filter By</h5>
                <div class="location my-3">
                    <select class="custom-select shadow-sm">
                        <option selected>1</option>
                        <option value="1">2</option>
                        <option value="2">3</option>
                        <option value="3">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="Budget my-3">
                    <select class="custom-select shadow-sm">
                        <option selected>100</option>
                        <option value="1">200</option>
                        <option value="2">300</option>
                        <option value="3">400</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Comment: You are asking about radio button, and there is no radio button in the code that you've shared. Your question is too unclear. Please read about how to post question, and edit your post to be understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying you want to fill the radio orange but you have a select element with options? Do you mean you want the selected option to be orange?

Else this example could work with correct classnames

```
.custom-radio .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::after {
  background-color: orange;
}
```